# Statement that force implement the before statement

Tags: tkinter, root

Is there any statement that force to implement statement in line 40 before the statement in line 41.Because after I capture the image, I still see the root window in the picture although I use root.withdraw() in code. I guess that the statement in line 41 doesn't process but the statement in line 41 implement. Can anyone help me, please?

```
def fullscreen():
    root.withdraw() #line 40
    roi_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None) #line 41
    root.deiconify() #line 42
    if roi_image: 
        preview(roi_image)
```

Comment: Try adding `root.update_idletasks()` between line 40 and line 41. If it doesn't work, try `root.update()`

Comment: I use two way, but the problems can't change

Answer (score 0):

It does get processed, after the `mainloop` gets to update it, which happens only after the whole function has completed. So you could define another function to be called after `mainloop` processes events using `after` to schedule an event for later (10 ms):

```py
def fullscreen():
    root.withdraw()  #line 40

    def func():
        roi_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)  #line 41
        root.deiconify()  #line 42
        if roi_image: 
            preview(roi_image)

    root.after(10, func)
```

The shorter solution using `.update`:

```py
def fullscreen():
    root.withdraw() #line 40
    root.update()
    roi_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None) #line 41
    root.deiconify() #line 42
    if roi_image: 
        preview(roi_image)
```

Comment: This is the same as adding `root.update()` between line 40 and line 41.

Comment: @TheLizzard I guess it is, tho `.update` is not really suggested?, maybe OP simply wrongly used it

Comment: It isn't encouraged, but the same problems would appear if you used `.after`. Basically `.update` can call user defined bindings (while the `fullscreen` function is still running) which can cause problems. Same thing will happen if you used `.after` in this case

Comment: @TheLizzard what would you propose instead then? probably possible to use threading but seems excessive